# berkeley db Multiple Keys in java

Tags: java, sql, berkeley-db

I am trying to figure out how to implement 'AND' in Berkely DB.
Like in SQL, where we can just name='john' **and** id='1234', Is there a function like this in Berkely DB?
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATED

thanks for the reply.

Example query :  String query = "2012/03/11 2012/03/08 2012/03/07"
So I have to grab all following dates from this data set

```
2012/03/11:000000010
2012/03/11:000000011
2012/03/11:000000012
2012/03/08:000000013
2012/03/07:000000014
2012/03/07:000000015
2012/03/07:000000016
2012/03/05:000000017
2012/03/05:000000018
2012/03/04:000000019
```

and return all corresponding strings

```
   000000019 abc
   000000013 dfe
         .
         .
         .
   000010000 xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can even store anything like that... BDB is a key-value store where each key is unique, so if your key is the `id` then just search for the `id`. However, if your key is something else, then you will have to do some tricky things to get it working. I can't give you much useful advice without knowing how you've structured your data and how you're storing it.

So how are you storing your data? What's the key and what's the value?

Comment: So back to the same question again: what's the key and what's the value? Your update still doesn't answer that question...

Comment: 2012/03/11 2012/03/08 2012/03/07 are the keys(query) and values are gonna be 'abc' 'dfe' 'xyz'. I hope this answered your question.